# rails 4 populate dropdown values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a dropdown in a rails form:

```
<%= f.select :lists, [["test1", 1], ["test2", 0]] %>
```

This works fine but how can I make it dynamic. (interacting with model data)

I have a controller with an action containing `@list = List.all`

How can I populate `id` and `name` in my `combobox`. I've been searching around, but I am unclear about it. Can anyone help>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select).

```
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id', 'name') %>
<%= f.select :all_val,  options %>
```

Comment: If i use `options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name')` getting error as  `undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass`. What mistake I am doing

Comment: I would guess that ```@people``` is nil. You are using ```@list``` in your question.

Comment: sorry that is copy paste mistake actually i have like this `<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id', 'name') %>` but same error

Comment: Then ```@list``` is ```nil```. Check for typos and that you are setting it in proper controller and action. Also this method only generates options, don't remove ```f.select```.

Comment: Ok tried like this `<%= f.select :list, options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id', 'name') %>` then too same error occurs

Comment: hey @overflow what did you corrected in controller? I'm getting similar error and I don't know what should I do in controller. Instead of **@list** I'm using **@rolenames**, which has **@rolenames=Rolename.all** in controller.

Answer (score 3):

Don't quite have enough reputation to respond to your question in the thread above @learner but there's a good chance that @overflow didn't have @list defined in his controller.

To solve my case I put my equivalent of **@list** (in this case **@restaurants**) in my "def new" method since I was using it to help create new items with associated restaurants.

```
# GET /specials/new
  def new
    @special = Special.new
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all // Look Here
  end
```

Additionally, **:all_val** in the original response should be the parameter you want to pass in to the database. In my case it was **:restaurant_id**

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
# view
<%= form.select(:list_id) do %>
    <% @list.each do |l| -%>
      <%= content_tag(:option, l.name, value: l.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
# controller
@list ||= List.all
```

`