# rails 4 populate dropdown values from database with selected item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was reading the thread [rails 4 populate dropdown values from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211385/rails-4-populate-dropdown-values-from-database)
This thread is about how populate a dropdown, but, how can I select a value by default in this list?
Like:

**Controller**

```
@states = States.all
@selected = States.find(2)
```

**View**

> <% options =
>   options_from_collection_for_select(@states, 'id', 'name')%>

And use the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a form helper with :selected ?

```
f.collection_select :id, @states, :id, :name , {:selected => advert.town.state.id}
```

You can take a look about more options here:
[apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Answer (score 0):

`options_from_collection_for_select` takes a 4th argument which is the selected value

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@states, 'id', 'name', @selected.id)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/ is a good place to look up API related questions like this one

Comment: I always have this error: undefined method `merge' for #<State:0x007fc36899f3a8>

Comment: Double check your controller code and verify that there is exactly this `@states = States.all`. Also check in your code that you are not doing something like `@states = @states.first`